# Creating alpha for UIImage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, alpha

I'm trying to create a feature in my app that allows the user to extract a specified area of an existing image, and save it as a png with alpha enabled.

I've put a `UIView` ontop of a `UIImageView` - the `imageView` displays the image, while you are drawing your mask on the transparent `view`. For drawing, I'm using `UIBezierPath`. The user are able to draw around the object, and the inside will temporarily fill in with black.

The user picks the image from photo roll, and it's presented in the underlying `UIImageView` as shown on the left image, and when the user has drawn a shape (which automatically closes), on the overlying `UIView`, it looks like the right image:

[image: Without mask]
[image: With drawn-on mask]

This is working as expected, but when the user then clicks "Crop", then the magic should start. So far, I've only been able to create a "mask" and save it as an image on the roll, as displayed here (never mind the aspect ratios, I'll fix that later):

[image: Saved "mask"]
[image: Image and the generated "mask"]

This is just a normal image, created from the path/shape, with colors(black on white, not black on transparent).
What I need is some way to use this "image" as the alpha channel for the original image.

I know that these are two completely separate things, that an alpha-channel isn't the same as an image, but I have the shape, so I would like to know if there's any possible way to "crop" or "alpha out" with my data. What I want to end up with, is a png of this cat's face, with the surroundings 100% transparent (or not even there), so that I can change the background, like this:

[image: Transparent white background]
[image: Transparent orange background]

**It's important to note** that I'm **not** talking about showing a `UIImage` in a `UIImageView` with applied mask, I'm talking about creating a new image, based on an existing image, combined with another image that I want to somehow convert to the first image's alpha channel, thus saving one image like above, with transparency.

I'm not too familiar with handling the data of images, so I was wondering if anyone know how to create a new image based on two images, one acting as alpha for the other, when **neither** of the images necessarily have an alpha channel to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method below will take your original image and the mask image (the black shape) and return a `UIImage` that includes only the content of the image covered by the mask:

```
+ (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *) mask
{
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskReference = mask.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference),
                                             NULL, // Decode is null
                                             YES // Should interpolate
                                             );

    CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask);
    CGImageRelease(imageMask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
    CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

The areas outside the mask will be transparent. You can then combine the resulting `UIImage` with a background color.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this in a day or two, but this looks like it takes the alpha of the second image, and apply it on the first, and I don't think the shape I'm creating has an alpha channel on it either as it is now, but I'll try to find a way to do that. I'd imagine both images should be the exact same size as well at this point. I'll try some stuff out and hopefully get back with good news soon:)

Comment: This worked at last. I found out I had already tried this, but as it turned out, one of the images I sent in had a dummy alpha-channel that screwed it up. When converting both to JPEG before sending to this method, it worked perfectly, thanks. (It seems like it doesn't work on iOS7 though)